# Can a C++11 initializer-list be used with a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Is this valid C++ to initialize a dynamic array of pointers to `nullptr`?

```
int x = 10;
int** p = new int*[ x ]{ };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code is valid and value initializes each element of the array.

For standard references, refer to *§5.3.4/17 [expr.new]*

> A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:
>   — `...`
>   — Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

and then *§8.5/7 [dcl.init]*

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — `...`
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

The last bullet applies to each array element in this case.